# json file with geo-coordinates

Tags: json

Do you know of a web site that has a json file I can download that contains the following data:

```
City Name or postcode
latitude in degrees
longitude in degrees
How many hours +- the city is from GMT (Ex: Boston is -5)

Nice to have but not required:
daylight savings time (Yes or No). Ex: Boston, Massachusetts uses daylight savings time and Phoenix, Arizona does not.
```

For now I'm looking to get the data for cities in the US. I will add other countries later if the web resource has multiple countries.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155918/list-of-major-cities-with-latitude-longitude-and-timezone, there are plenty of web sites that will convert the csv to JSON.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I will be checking out the links to the post you referred to see which one is the best choice for me.